# Using flex in Qt project

Tags: qt, qt4, parser-generator, flex++

I need to use a flex++ generated parser code in my Qt application. I got this error:

```
  undefined reference to `yyFlexLexer::yywrap()
```

I also added this line to .pro file:

```
LIBS += -lfl
```

Comment: Is that a typo in your post or do you really have `LIBIS` somewhere?

Comment: Did you use the [LEXSOURCES](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html#lexsources) qmake property?

Comment: Well, you should at least try. If it fixes your issue, then you should definitely use it :-)

Comment: I tried to add `LEXSOURCES=lex.yy.cc` and got 995 errors, so I guess should add rules file, true? but `LEXSOURCES=rules.l` not helped... There is nothing about LEXSOURCES variable in documentation !

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is a simple

```
%option noyywrap
```

in the Options section

```
%{
    DECLARATION
%}
OPTIONS
%%
RULES
%%
MISC. C IMPLEMENTATION
```

and maby you want to add these as well:

```
%option nounistd
%option never-interactive
```